# Windows desktop program to save your computer session - based on restore session when programs crash

Tags: python, c#, c++, windows, google-chrome

I want to create a windows desktop program that will allow you to save your computer session to be able to restore it later.

I know that it should be possible to do this as chrome has a restore session where it restores tabs that were open before a crash - microsoft office programs have autosave where it restores your session before a crash - etc - so somewhere on the computer there is a function that it is able to take a snapshot of a session and restore it.

I think this program could be possible by taking information from the task manager at the time of the session and then restoring it from there.

What I don't know is what would I need to do to get a program like this to work.

What programming language would work best for getting this done. I am a beginner to python but have heard that C/C++/C# allows for more control over the processes of the computer than python does.

Also is it correct in thinking that this type of program would work by looking into the task manager at the running programs/processes and saving the information on the session from there or do the restore sessions / autosave functions work another way.

Thanks.

Comment: You're talking about a pretty complicated thing. Do you just want to re-launch the same programs that were running prior, or do you want those programs to be in the exact same state they were before the crash?

Comment: restoring the state of your program is trivial ... restoring state to the whole computer is while not impossible, not very feasible of a task

Comment: This is a *huge* and difficult task. That is not what Stackoverflow questions are for - they are for *specific* and *focused* questions about some single thing that can be answered with a short fact based answer. This is not such a question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I think, perhaps, this question is a bit too broad for this forum.  Stack Overflow is better suited to answer *targeted* question about programming than it is about broad questions like "How do I go about making my program".  Once you have started your program and run into specific errors or problems with your code, please come back and see us!

Comment: Save/restore session functions are all different. Chrome has it because the developers of the application implemented it. Office has it because the developers of Office implemented it. There is no system defined way of saving the operating state of an arbitrary program and restoring it, and doing so in the system, with all of the system services and loaded drivers, is going to be very difficult.

Comment: You *might* be able to do this with the right team of skilled professionals and some 5-10 years of time (would be my guess). Good luck. Just saving the kernel state and figure out how to restore that is going to be a challenge. And how will you deal with network connections that have long since died? What about the state of input devices? What if the user swapped out some hardware? It is *not* simple.

Comment: Joran Beasley - I want to be able to restore the state of a program for example someone working on a project may have a chrome session with a bunch of tabs open and a few microsoft word windows all for their project - I would want them to be able to take those programs at their current state to choose as their snapshot and then restore that session at a later time - thanks.

Comment: Also can someone answer that to get something like this done what programming language would be best?

Comment: "looking into the task manager at the running programs/processes and saving the information on the session from there" - If your depth of knowledge into operating system internals amount to thinking that just looking through the lens that "task manager" gives you, amounts to a complete view of the system and its state, then I'm sorry to say that you are 1) wrong. 2) have a *lot* to learn.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know but you have to start from somewhere - this is what I want to get done and I'm asking because I don't know how and I want to get closer to being able to get it done - what programming language could I use to do this and how could I be able to deconstruct something like the chrome restore session or microsoft office autosave to see how it can be done.

Comment: @JoranBeasley You said restoring the state of your program is trivial - how could that be done - that is what my question was trying to ask.

Comment: you save the bits that are important to whatever **your program** is as you work ... if you crash you just restore the data from where you saved it (a db a file on disk) ... a typical thing might be some text editor ... you save at each keystroke (or in a global try/except) if something crashes you reload the text in your `.backup.current_file_text` or whatever and put it back into the text area the user works with

Comment: @JoranBeasley How would I do this for the chrome browser to restore a session with all the tabs that are opened in that session.

Comment: chrome does this by maintaining a list of tabs that are open, and when restarting offering to reopen the same ones... this is no different than my example above with the text editor.  instead you would be making a multi tabbed browser ... but to try and hook into this functionality from outside would require alot of research and knowlege about the underlying code for every program you tried to support ...

Comment: chrome maintains this for you so you can see their docs here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs

Comment: If you were to start your apps via the shell when choosing the document, you can get the startup command line to relaunch that document at some later point. You can also get the size and location of the app's main window. I would leave file recovery up to the app that would potentially crash.  You could create a service in the background that keeps track of things.  The service would need to run under your login credentials. C# would be well-suited for this type of thing. Plenty of documentation regarding process enumeration and services. This would be a good session management utility.

Answer (score 3):

Your main assumption is wrong - there is no function in the system to save and restore the state of a running program on a crash. Office implements this by periodically saving a copy of your documents in the background, allowing you to restore from the shadow copy Office saved for you. Chrome implements this with a browser history tracker, and knowing what tabs were open is much simpler than tracking everything in them.

Extending this concept to the whole system is.... exceedingly difficult. You would have to write code that would save the operating state of all executing programs on the system, without saving the state of the crashing program, as that would cause your restore to crash the system. This would require determining what caused the system to crash, which requires solving the halting problem, which isn't possible.

If you want this behavior for an individual application you're building, implement it for that application in particular. If you want this for the whole system... you're SOL.

Comment: Have an upvote. There's a reason why high availability systems with triple redundancy and the ability to recover from most crashes, cost millions.

Comment: Hell, my job is building industrial automation systems for hosptials, airports and large buildings and our focus is just on not crashing to begin with. If you crash, that's it. Just restart and try not to next time.

Comment: I work with medical imaging and our focus is the same. Just don't crash. If you do; game over, restart from scratch - you cannot hope to ever restart at the same state.

Comment: Not to mention - what if your state caused the crash?

Comment: Indeed. And solving that conundrum is either impossible or too expensive to be worth the effort.

Comment: Hello, I want it to be able to save a snapshot of your session - I only mentioned crashing as an example to show you when other restore session/autosave functions kick in for other programs - this has nothing to do with crashing - Just saving a snapshot of the session and being able to restore it to that session.

Comment: @spgplayerstack Define "*session*" then. In much, *much* more detail. What *exactly* do you want to restore? Are you thinking "VM snapshot" maybe? Filesystem snapshot? Or *what*?

Comment: Still an insanely difficult prospect. All your network connections are ephemeral, so anything that depends on network state is almost certainly going to crash on restore. Any disk transactions cannot be in progress, or the data on disk will get corrupted. If a program is waiting for a real time timer to expire, it will expire as soon as the restore is completed, possibly causing timing failures if deltas are too large. If a program uses rdtsc on an x86/64 machine, time may appear to flow backwards, resulting in extremely strange or incorrect behavior.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl Windows defines a session as a single user's active logon. So long as there's no clarification that's what I'm assuming is meant.

Comment: @Alex that doesn't say *anything* about the current state of running programs. Nor anything about the state of the kernel or hardware. It is too vague to be useful for anything.

Comment: Its all of the programs started when you log on, every service running, your instance of the shell... it's a lot, but not everything. And it doesn't take into account shared data, code, or kernel state.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm not experienced so I don't know how to call it by its name. By session I mean exactly like the chrome restore session and microsoft office autosave features - where they will basically take a snapshot of what you were last doing and then be able to bring back what you were doing on those programs.

Comment: @spgplayerstack "I'm not experienced" - then you are in *way* over your head here. Even if all running programs supported a snapshot feature (they don't), restoring them all to that state would be a big chunk of work. Getting something like this working for *arbitrary* programs is going to be insanely hard. Even for a team of experts with years to spend on the task.  For a single inexperienced programmer, I'd say it's impossible.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks for explaining - If I was to focus on just the Chrome browser to get the restore session on demand - rather than only available after a crash - as the browser is the most important program for most people - so could this be doable if I was to focus on just chrome making the restore session function work on demand being able to restore all open tabs from a session. Thanks.

Comment: here is the developer documentation for chrome tabs https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs